# Изменение URL после переадресации Dispatcher-ом JSP

Tags: url, jsp, servlet, request

Не меняется URL после переадресации на страницу dispatcher-ом с сервлета.

Есть страница авторизации(**index.jsp** - стартовая страница), есть страница куда попадают юзеры после успешной авторизацииB. Есть сервлет Auth, в котором происходит авторизация. Используется метод Post.
Сервлет обращается к классу который производит подключение к бд и проверяет есть ли такой юзер(проверяет логин и пароль тоже) и возвращает **ture** или **false**. Если он вернёт **false** то на главной странице в форме авторизации появится текст ошибки. По этой причине мне приходится использовать **Dispatcher**. Если возвращается ошибка да и если успешная авторизация URL не меняется. Он он так и остаётся "/Auth".

Вопрос как решать данную проблему? sendRedirect мне не подходит ибо мне нужно выводить сообщение об ошибке если такова будет. А так sendRedirect изменяет ссылку.

Как выйти с этого положения?